# Quantizing the EM field: "The $\boldsymbol{k}_{\perp},k_z,\omega$ approach"

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, second-quantization

I came across [this "tutorial"](https://doi.org/10.1088/2040-8986/ab89e4) (check [this link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01184) for an arxiv version of the article) which in equation (18) gives the following form for the field operators for electromagnetic field:

$$ \hat{E}^{ \left(+\right)}\!\left(\boldsymbol{r},t\right) = \int\mathrm{d}^2\boldsymbol{k}_{\perp}\int\mathrm{d}\omega E_0e^{i\left(\boldsymbol{k}_{\perp}\cdot\boldsymbol{\rho}+k_zz-\omega t\right)} \hat{a}\!\left(\boldsymbol{k}_{\perp},\omega\right)$$

Where $\boldsymbol{\rho}$ refers to the vector of the $x$ and $y$ components of $\boldsymbol{r}$.

In particular, notice that the integral in $\boldsymbol{k}_{\perp}$ extends only over the $x$$y$-plane and not over the $k_z$ direction. Instead, an integral over the frequency appears. I have never seen this kind of field quantization anywhere. Normally, I would have expected an integral over all of $\boldsymbol{k}$, that is $\int\mathrm{d}^2\boldsymbol{k}_{\perp}\int\mathrm{d}\omega\rightarrow\int\mathrm{d}^3\boldsymbol{k}$.

Equation (17) provides a bit of an explanation, but this does not explain for example why this quantization is possible and correct (and complete).

Is there a more formal explanation for this quantization of the EM field? If possible, please provide papers, references to books etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the electric field satisfies a wave equation, then each Fourier mode $(\mathbf{k},\omega) $ satisfy $ |\mathbf{k}|^2 = |\mathbf{k}_\perp|^2 + k_z^2 = \omega^2 $ ($c$ = 1).

Thus, it is just a question of how to integrate over all the Fourier modes that satisfy this equation. One common way is to integrate over all momenta $\mathbf{k}$, and $\omega = \pm|\mathbf{k}|$, but the authors chose to integrate over $\mathbf{k_\perp}$ and $\omega$ instead, with $k_z = \pm\sqrt{\omega^2 - |\mathbf{k}_\perp|^2}$. In both ways we are getting the same expansion.